# Android Studio 2.0 - Rebuild backend classes

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio-2.0

I'm building an Android app with the backend running on GAE. It all works great, love it. However, if I do any updates to my `UserBean` class in the `backend` module, the changes don't get replicated to the `app` module. I've tried clean, rebuild, make, restarting android studio, and rebooting machine.

For example, my original class was under the package `com.example.projectname.backend`. That's the the backend module of the project. It had a function named `getValid()`. I started using it on the front end, which is a different module named `app`. Then I changed the function name to `isValid()`. However, it doesn't look like the new version of the class isn't being compiled for the front end to use. When I call `getValid()` on the front end, it compiles no problem, but always returns false, no matter what I do in the backend class. When I call `isValid()` in the front end, it gives compile a error, saying it can't find the function.

Am I missing something that makes the changes made on backend classes reflect on front end classes? Or maybe there is a better structure to use? This structure seems to be the one that Google uses in their tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The app module doesn't get a full copy of the object on the backend. I guess this makes sense, as it passes the data as a JSON string through the network. On the front end, all it has is the `getter`s and `setter`s. Any functionality would be run solely on the backend.